# Episode 50 of the venerable Stack Exchange podcast is expected when?

Tags: discussion, podcast

The last Stack Exchange Podcast ([episode 49](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/podcast-49-the-one-where-we-edited-out-the-title-reference/)) was released one month and eight days ago.

This leads to the following two questions:

1. When will podcast #50 drop on the streets?
2. Why the delay?

### **Update:** [Link to episode 50](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/07/podcast-50-listen-to-this-podcast/).

Comment: It's #50, so we had to make sure it was EXTRA AWESOME. Also, I was out for 2 weeks...  but mostly the AWESOME part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We *just* recorded another episode - the fabled Episode #50. The recent changes to closing are discussed, we argue inconclusively about library recommendation questions, and Joel smashes blinds in the recording room. Will anyone make it out alive? Stay tuned...

It should be live on the blog sometime next week.

Comment: Great! I can't wait!

Comment: It seems to have [been prematurely announced](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nWyvn.png) - following that link at the time of writing this [leads to "oh no, 404"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/haPry.png).

Comment: Works for me, @Peter - the link should be http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/07/podcast-50-listen-to-this-podcast/?cb=1 - does that work?

Comment: I still get the 404. The link is http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/07/podcast-50-listen-to-this-podcast/?cb=1. I also tried it in Opera with the same result, not being logged into Stack Overflow.

Comment: Not seeing any requests logged for you, @peter - are you behind a caching proxy of any sort?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Perhaps at my ISP, 3.dk. As far as I know (from a traceroute), there are several NATs between me and the Internet, but I have not encountered this kind of problem before.

Comment: Anyway, the podcast is available from http://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/#feeds

Comment: I found the reason. For some reason, on 2009-12-12, I had put in an entry (now deleted) in the [hosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) file (C:\WINDOWS\system32\Drivers\etc\hosts): "69.59.196.214    blog.stackoverflow.com" (the new address is 198.252.206.20). One hint was that [tracert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) and [nslookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nslookup) gave different results.